# Is it possible to Work on a same TFS file by same user ID in different location on the same time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am working from my client building,another one person is working on another location.We both  have to work on a same file by using same user Id on same time ,Is it possible on TFS ,visual studio 2010?

Please advice me..

Comment: I did not try this, but I think it should be possible.  But why just add another account in TFS? It's so easy!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  A single user - by which I mean a user in the logged-in user term, obviously TFS has no idea who's actually sitting at the keyboard - can check a file out multiple times.  Pending changes are per *workspace*, and a workspace is uniquely identified by the name, client computer and user.  So since you're coming from two different client computers, you will need two workspaces.

That said, I don't know what the requirement to not simply have two accounts is, but it seems like your TFS history loses something (traceability?  accountability?  etc. etc.) when you look at it and one user did all the work.  Unless, of course, you've cleverly hired some interns to boost your productivity, thus giving you a raise greater than what you're paying your interns.  If that's the case, then congratulations on your clever manipulation of the system.